# Jquery function : Get img width and Height then addClass dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-processing

I'm stuck in Jquery on a function that recovers the width and height of an image.

The idea is simple:

If my image is less wide than it is long, then add my class...
Otherwise add another class.

It works but not all the time I feel like:

example with this page:

https://www.jean-desazars.com/advanced-portfolio-test/

(Click on the first image)
My image is too high and therefore exceeds the content, I'd like it to fit in the pop up without scroll and resize.

So I wanted to make it so that IF the image exceeds a size X, I add a class to it to be able to manipulate it in css according to the cases.

However I have the impression that the image is defined after loading the DOM (at the click and opening of the popup) and therefore that he did not find it.

So I went through a naturalWidth / naturalHeight, but no matter the size of the image, the class added remains the same.

would you have an idea please ? Even without JS I'm a taker, my constraint is that each image has a different size, but no matter how big it is it has to fit without scroll.

Thanks for your help ;)

Have a nice evening ! :)

CODE :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgs = $('.wpb-fp-main-image img');//jQuery class selector
  imgs.each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var width = img.naturalWidth; //jQuery height method
    var height = img.naturalHeight; //jQuery height method
    if(height > width){
       img.addClass('img-h');
    }else{
       img.addClass('img-n');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?  All of the images to be within a max-height and maintain their aspect ratio?  You should be able to do this with just css.  Try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Being a wordpress site, without knowing which css is your custom css and which is the theme's css that needs to be overridden, it's hard to say what to do.  Is this your css: `.wpb_fp_quick_view_img.wpb_fp_has_gallery img {max-height: 100vh!important;}`?  Looks like changing that to `76vh` should do the trick for the height but to maintain aspect ratio you need to get rid of the `width: 100%` and just have `max-width: 100%` for the class `.wpb_fp_quick_view img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply change the `max-height` of image from `100vh` to `max-height: calc(100vh-100px)` in your CSS. (100px is the size of your header)

[image: The change you need to make]

The `img`:
[image: The image]

Comment: You can change the `100px` according to the height of your header. Just look at what suits you.